# reading and writing text file from VBA, the EOF() iteration only works 10% of the time

Tags: vba, text, replace, iteration, file-writing

I was trying to write a sub to rewrite line 27 of a text file. But the `EOF(1)` seems only work 10% of the time. Other times it just directly run down with the 1st loop, and returns nothing. Anyone know the reason?

```vb
Dim File As String

Dim VecFile() As String, Aux As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim SizeNewFile As Long

Open (filepath) For Input As 1
i = 0
j = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    j = j + 1
    Line Input #1, Aux
    If j <> 27 Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve VecFile(1 To i)
        VecFile(i) = Aux
    End If
Loop
Close #1
SizeNewFile = i

'Write array to file
Open ("filepath") For Output As 1
For i = 1 To 26
    Print #1, VecFile(i)
Next i

Print #1, "\newcommand\casenumber{" & Sheets("Database").Range("$B$1").Value & "}" & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
For i = 28 To SizeNewFile
    Print #1, VecFile(i)
Next i

Close #1
```

I got Run time error 9, subscript out of range.

Comment: `I got Run time error 9, subscript out of range` - apparently because your file had less than 26 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Tester\Modify Me.txt"
    
    Dim arr, txt
    
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        
        txt = .opentextfile(FILE_PATH, 1).readall()  'read all content
        arr = Split(txt, vbCrLf)                     'zero-based array from file content
        'modify content if reached required # of lines
        If UBound(arr) >= 26 Then arr(26) = "---New line goes here---" 
  
        
        txt = Join(arr, vbCrLf)
        .opentextfile(FILE_PATH, 2, True).write txt  'write back modified text
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```